# Are dynamic routes possible in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

Can route's be dynamic? I am thinking this is an important feature because:

1. Most routes would not be accessible for a user who is not authenticated
2. Once the user authenticates new routes should be added

Seems like many web apps would share these requirements. How can Router.map be used to achieve these goals?

Comment: This gist may help you https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if creating new routes dynamically is a good idea as it can mess up many things. If you only need this for authentication then I recommend to check out [ember-auth](https://github.com/heartsentwined/ember-auth). Or you can write your own authentication mechanism like in the [gist](https://gist.github.com/machty/5647589) recommended in previous comment.

If you need to hide some links from the UI then you can just use some if-else constructs from your view like:

```
{{if isAuthenticated}}
  <!-- Show some links -->
{{else}}
  <!-- Show login link -->
{{/if}}
```

Note that this only hides the links. User can still enter the route URL directly, therefore the ember-auth or custom authentication mechanism is needed that will prevent the route from loading by checking the isAuthenticated flag also in beforeModel hook.

Comment: I want to implement a conception, just load what user need instead load all data or js file at beginning (even route data).